# Free vector design app besides inkscape?

Tags: vector, software-recommendation

Does anyone know a good **vector** drawing application?

I tried Inkscape, but it is not a *real* vector design app. Technically it's an SVG editor, and as such doesn't support anything that SVG doesn't support.

I'm missing these features in Inkscape/SVG (and I don't care about SVG anyway, I just want to draw on screen/paper, not web):

- Support for multiple pages*, so I can design and print booklets / practice sheets / etc.
- Center a text in any shape/group that doesn't stray or stretch when the shape size is changed. Word-wrap is required. (Read carefully -- this is impossible to do with Text-flow!)
- Can easily create arrows with any size arrowhead* and any color*.
- Have 'anchors' on shapes so other shapes (typically lines) move when the shape in question is moved/scaled.

*(known Inkscape bug/shortcoming with very awkward workaround)

Text-in-shape Example:
[image: Text-in-shape Example]
Anchors Example:
[image: Anchors Example]

Answer (score 2):

> Support for multiple pages*, so I can design and print booklets / practice sheets / etc.

Macromedia Freehand had that feature. We all loved it. Adobe killed it.

Anyways, that's really not a feature that is typical of an illustration app. That's more of a page layout/publishing app such as Adobe InDesign. For a decent open source option, try Scribus.

> Center a text in any shape/group that doesn't stray or stretch when the shape size is changed. Word-wrap is required. (Read carefully -- this is impossible to do with Text-flow!)

Inkscape handles resizable text boxes with the text re-flowing as needed.

Again, though, complex typography and text flow is more of a page layout feature (again, see Scribus).

> Can easily create arrows with any size arrowhead* and any color*.

Relative easy to do by creating your own arrowhead and duplicating as needed.

> Have 'anchors' on shapes so other shapes (typically lines) move when the shape in question is moved/scaled.

Not quite sure what you are looking for there. Could you clarify that one a bit more?

Inkscape is typically considered the most mature of the open source options for vector illustration (in fact, it's all I use for my freelance work these days). That said, there are some alternatives. I haven't tried these. If you do, report back and let us know how they work out!

- http://www.skencil.org/ (UI akin to Inkscape, not sure if it's still maintained)
- http://www.xaraxtreme.org/ (powerful, but also not sure if it's still being developed)
- https://live.gnome.org/Dia (looks to specifically have featured tailored to flow charts and diagramming)
- http://sk1project.org/ (apparently formally Skencil, and now, replaced with PrintDesign. More info on PrintDesign here: http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/sk1-development-restarted alas, I can't find a URL for printDesign. It looks interesting as it's specifically CMYK based, which would be nice).

Comment: I think he means for example an arrow to a box and "anchoring" it meaning if he then moves the box that control point of the arrow will also move. OpenOffice.org Draw makes that really easy to do actually. I used it a lot when illustrating a textbook.

Comment: ah! Yea, that's a neat feature. One that I think Freehand also had! Alas, that's also not really a focus of illustration apps. That's more of a flow charting feature (and there are open source flow charting apps).

Comment: I guess perhaps another way to put it, the features being requested, while valid and would be great to have, aren't really features one typically finds in illustration software. I think the best solution might be to use different types of software for the particular task at hand.

Comment: Do you not like OpenOffice.org?

Comment: I can't say I have a strong opinion about OpenOffice one way or the other. ;)

Comment: I don't use OOo. I use Libreoffice, altough I haven't installed Drawing. (the draw app in OOo (when I still used it) really disappointed me so I expected not much from this) I used MS Visio for a while, it does everything i want (to some extent (arrowheads are in 7 predefined sizes) but it isn't free and it has some nasty bugs and other limitations)

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice.org does everything you've just described. For more complex books (the multi page feature you seek) you might also want to look into Scribus.

- http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html
- http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus

Comment: +1 for OOo. It fits the description. How good is Scribus these days? It's supposed to fit the bill, but I tried to work with it about a year and half ago and the bloody thing kept crashing.

Comment: OOo Draw has all the features, but on the other end it is quite primitive.